# OpenVPN network adapter on Windows machine keeps getting/losing IP address every 15 seconds

Tags: windows, networking, openvpn, ip-address

I have an instance of Windows Server 2019. I installed [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/) 2.4.9 on it. This resulted in a new network adapter called "Local Area Connection / TAP-Windows Adapter V9" as seen in the Control Panel:

[image]

This Windows machine is acting as an OpenVPN client. Here is the OpenVPN client configuration on the machine:

```
client
dev tap
proto tcp
remote x.x.x.x 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
block-outside-dns
verb 3
```

Another machine is acting as the OpenVPN server. Here is that machine's server.conf:

```
local x.x.x.x
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tap
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.0.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
```

I am trying to have the OpenVPN server assign a static IP address of 10.8.0.2 to the Windows Server 2019 machine. Here is the file under the OpenVPN server's /etc/openvpn/ccd directory for the client:

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.0.2 255.255.0.0
```

When the OpenVPN client on the Windows Server 2019 starts, it appears to connect to the OpenVPN server fine. Here is the log file on the OpenVPN client:

```
Wed Jul 14 01:15:02 2021 [server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]x.x.x.x:1194
Wed Jul 14 01:15:03 2021 SENT CONTROL [server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Wed Jul 14 01:15:03 2021 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,route-gateway 10.8.0.1,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.2 255.255.0.0,peer-id 0,cipher AES-256-GCM'
Wed Jul 14 01:15:03 2021 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Wed Jul 14 01:15:03 2021 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Wed Jul 14 01:15:03 2021 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
Wed Jul 14 01:15:03 2021 OPTIONS IMPORT: peer-id set
Wed Jul 14 01:15:03 2021 OPTIONS IMPORT: adjusting link_mtu to 1658
Wed Jul 14 01:15:03 2021 OPTIONS IMPORT: data channel crypto options modified
Wed Jul 14 01:15:03 2021 Data Channel: using negotiated cipher 'AES-256-GCM'
Wed Jul 14 01:15:03 2021 Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Wed Jul 14 01:15:03 2021 Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Wed Jul 14 01:15:03 2021 interactive service msg_channel=0
Wed Jul 14 01:15:03 2021 open_tun
Wed Jul 14 01:15:03 2021 TAP-WIN32 device [Local Area Connection] opened: \\.\Global\{526EF9D3-DC84-41B0-B139-F1D4BAEFBF4F}.tap
Wed Jul 14 01:15:03 2021 TAP-Windows Driver Version 9.24 
Wed Jul 14 01:15:03 2021 Notified TAP-Windows driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 10.8.0.2/255.255.0.0 on interface {526EF9D3-DC84-41B0-B139-F1D4BAEFBF4F} [DHCP-serv: 10.8.0.0, lease-time: 31536000]
Wed Jul 14 01:15:03 2021 Successful ARP Flush on interface [11] {526EF9D3-DC84-41B0-B139-F1D4BAEFBF4F}
Wed Jul 14 01:15:03 2021 Block_DNS: WFP engine opened
Wed Jul 14 01:15:03 2021 Block_DNS: Using existing sublayer
Wed Jul 14 01:15:03 2021 Block_DNS: Added permit filters for exe_path
Wed Jul 14 01:15:03 2021 Block_DNS: Added block filters for all interfaces
Wed Jul 14 01:15:03 2021 Block_DNS: Added permit filters for TAP interface
Wed Jul 14 01:15:08 2021 TEST ROUTES: 0/0 succeeded len=-1 ret=0 a=0 u/d=down
Wed Jul 14 01:15:08 2021 Route: Waiting for TUN/TAP interface to come up...
Wed Jul 14 01:15:13 2021 TEST ROUTES: 0/0 succeeded len=-1 ret=0 a=0 u/d=down
Wed Jul 14 01:15:13 2021 Route: Waiting for TUN/TAP interface to come up...
Wed Jul 14 01:15:14 2021 TEST ROUTES: 0/0 succeeded len=-1 ret=0 a=0 u/d=down
Wed Jul 14 01:15:14 2021 Route: Waiting for TUN/TAP interface to come up...
Wed Jul 14 01:15:15 2021 TEST ROUTES: 0/0 succeeded len=-1 ret=0 a=0 u/d=down
Wed Jul 14 01:15:15 2021 Route: Waiting for TUN/TAP interface to come up...
Wed Jul 14 01:15:16 2021 TEST ROUTES: 0/0 succeeded len=-1 ret=0 a=0 u/d=down
Wed Jul 14 01:15:16 2021 Route: Waiting for TUN/TAP interface to come up...
Wed Jul 14 01:15:17 2021 TEST ROUTES: 0/0 succeeded len=-1 ret=0 a=0 u/d=down
Wed Jul 14 01:15:17 2021 Route: Waiting for TUN/TAP interface to come up...
Wed Jul 14 01:15:18 2021 TEST ROUTES: 0/0 succeeded len=0 ret=1 a=0 u/d=up
Wed Jul 14 01:15:18 2021 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Wed Jul 14 01:15:18 2021 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

As you can see, the OpenVPN client is receiving the 10.8.0.2 IP address from the OpenVPN server. However, I am repeatedly doing `ipconfig` in a command line window, and what I see is that every 15 seconds, the following happens:

- the "Local Area Connection" adapter gets an IP address of 169.254.211.103 for a few seconds
- then the "Local Area Connection" adapter gets an IP address of 10.8.0.2 for one second. During this one second, a ping of 10.8.0.1 (the OpenVPN server) will be successful.
- then the "Local Area Connection" adapter does not show any IP address for the next ~12 seconds
- this process keeps repeating every 15 seconds

While this is happening, I can see the adapter in the Control Panel sometimes changes to "Identifying...":

[image]

If the OpenVPN client is getting the 10.8.0.2 address from the OpenVPN server, then why is the adapter first having a 169.254.x.x address assigned? Then why does it have the 10.8.0.2 address assigned for only 1 second before it loses it?

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**

The 10.8.0.2 IP address had actually been assigned to a different machine before yesterday - a Linux instance running in AWS. Then I did the following:

- deleted the Linux instance in AWS
- used the [Nyr OpenVPN](https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install) openvpn-install.sh script on the OpenVPN server to revoke that Linux client
- deleted the file on the OpenVPN server's /etc/openvpn/ccd directory for the Linux client
- added a new file in the OpenVPN server's /etc/openvpn/ccd directory for the Windows Server 2019 machine with 10.8.0.2 as its IP address

I have verified in the OpenVPN server's /etc/openvpn/ccd directory that 10.8.0.2 is only being assigned to the Windows Server 2019 machine, and not to any other machine.

I just tried having the OpenVPN server assign 10.8.0.11 to the Windows Server 2019 machine, and it works fine, no problems at all. So something is wrong with that 10.8.0.2 address, probably because of the fact that it had been previously used. Any idea what that might be?

I would prefer to be able to use the 10.8.0.2 address, because we have already written scripts assuming 10.8.0.2 will be the static IP, and sent those scripts to a third-party. It will be easier to stick with 10.8.0.2, if possible.

**MORE INFORMATION**

I decided to try to eliminate any trace of the old Linux client from the OpenVPN server:

- I deleted it from the /etc/openvpn/server/easy-rsa/pki/index.txt file.
- I deleted its certificate from the /etc/openvpn/server/easy-rsa/pki/revoked/certs_by_serial directory.

I also noticed that the OpenVPN server's /etc/openvpn/server/ipp.txt file contained an association of the old Linux client to 10.8.0.2, and an association of the Windows Server 2019 client to an incorrect IP address. I deleted the ipp.txt file.

Then I restarted the OpenVPN server, and had the Windows 2019 Server's OpenVPN client reconnect. Unfortunately I still get the same behavior as before.

**UPDATE:**

I didn't look at the Windows Server 2019 machine for a few days, and now I just looked at it again. Surprisingly it had the 10.8.0.2 IP address and it never disappeared. Everything was working as expected. I'm not sure why, as I didn't change anything.

So I restarted the OpenVPN client on the Windows Server 2019 machine to see what would happen, and now it is back to the behavior of getting a 169.254.x.x address then getting and losing the 10.8.0.2 address every 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an IP address conflict, as indicated by the system event log on the Windows Server 2019 instance.

We have some additional Linux servers running OpenVPN clients (different from the Linux client that I mentioned in the question). Each of these Linux servers has a bridge set up with the IP address 10.8.0.2. This bridge connects the tap0 interface of the OpenVPN client to the eth1 interface which is attached to a vendor's device. This setup allows the vendor's software running on the Windows Server 2019 instance to connect to the device.

I powered off the Linux servers and rebooted the Windows Server 2019 instance. The Windows Server 2019 instance was able to obtain 10.8.0.2 without losing it. Then I booted up the Linux servers, and everything is working fine now. The Windows Server 2019 and Linux instances are happy, and the software running on the Windows Server is able to connect to the devices attached to the Linux servers through OpenVPN.

So the solution is to just make sure the Windows Server 2019 instance boots up before any of the Linux instances set up their bridge.

Edit: An easier solution is to just restart the OpenVPN server and then immediately start the OpenVPN client on the Windows Server 2019 instance. It will obtain 10.8.0.2 before any of the Linux instances are able to reconnect to the OpenVPN server.